# I can not filter by 3 level nested properties using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, .net-5

I am facing a problem while trying to query some data in my database based on some sub property filter.

If I filter this subproperty once I have loaded in memory my result, it works. But I would like doing it with a fully eager load.

The query I am using looks like the following (the example is simplified have some extra ThenIncludes before).

```
query.Include(...)
.ThenInclude(...)
.ThenInclude(i => 
    i.Questions.Where(question => 
           question.AssetTypes.Contains(asset.AssetType)))
```

The problem is that the filter by `AssetTypes` is never applied and I get `Questions` back that are not related to the `asset.AssetType` I am filtering by.

Right now I think maybe EF is still not able to translate those nestings, and I am meanwhile filtering it after load. At this moment it is not a problem because my application does not have so many `Questions` and lest than ten `AssetTypes`. However I would like to know if this possible to do on the query.

Comment: What happens if you replace the where with any? ie: i.Questions.Any(a => a.AssetTypes.Contains(asset.AssetType)))

Comment: @Gh DevOps Hello, I have not tried it yet, but I will do! thanks for the hint

Comment: @GHDevOps I was just going with your sueggestion, but the problem is this would not work because I don't want to add all questions when any, but rather add just the questions where its asset type contains an AssetType...